# How to tranform SELECT sql query results in an array in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

This is a very general need and can help many people. It appears whenever we need to group information and summarize the grouped values as a string as follows:

| person | Visit Date | Visit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| First | 2020-01-02 | 0 |
| First | 2020-01-03 | 1 |
| First | 2020-01-04 | 1 |
| First | 2020-01-05 | 0 |
| Second | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| Second | 2020-01-02 | 1 |
| Second | 2020-01-03 | 1 |
| Second | 2020-01-04 | 0 |
| Second | 2020-01-05 | 1 |

Grouping values by the person column:

| person | MIN(Visit Date) | Sequence of Visits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 2020-01-01 | 10110 |
| Second | 2020-01-01 | 01101 |

I am using Athena for this solution so I am not as free to write a procedural function.

Answer (score 1):

In Athena, you would use `array_agg()` for this.  But unfortunately, it comes with this very [loud warning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/arrays-and-aggregation.html):

> ORDER BY is not supported for aggregation functions, for example, you cannot use it within array_agg(x).

And I assume that ordering is important.

If you know that maximum number of values for each group, you can use conditional aggregation like this:

```
select person, min(date),
       ( max(case when seqnum = 1 then value else '' end) ||
         max(case when seqnum = 2 then value else '' end) ||
         max(case when seqnum = 3 then value else '' end) ||
         max(case when seqnum = 4 then value else '' end) ||
         max(case when seqnum = 5 then value else '' end)
       ) as values_5
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by person;
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much. I think your solution solves most cases. In my example, it may not be as generic because I don't know how many elements each sequence will have and the ordering really makes a lot of difference to the sequence. Is there a way to build a function and call it by athena like this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-udf.html

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, you can use the combination of *reduce* and *array_agg* as follows:

```
WITH example_table AS
 (SELECT 'First' as person, '2020-01-01' as _date, 1 as _value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'First', '2020-01-02', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'First', '2020-01-03', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Second', '2020-01-01', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Second', '2020-01-02', 0)
SELECT person, min(_date), reduce(array_agg(_value ORDER BY _date), '', (s, x) -> CAST(s as varchar) || CAST(x as varchar), s -> s)
FROM example_table
GROUP BY person
```

The `array_agg(_value ORDER BY _date)` will create `ARRAY [1,0,1]`, for example, for the `first` person. The *reduce* part is concatenating the varchar of the numbers in the above array.

For the specific output of varchar, you can also use *array_join*, which makes it even shorter:

```
WITH example_table AS
 (SELECT 'First' as person, '2020-01-01' as _date, 1 as _value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'First', '2020-01-02', 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'First', '2020-01-03', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Second', '2020-01-01', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Second', '2020-01-02', 0)
SELECT person, min(_date), array_join(array_agg(_value ORDER BY _date),'')
FROM example_table
GROUP BY person
```

BTW, try to avoid using generic names such as *value* or *date* in your column name. You will most likely hit some reserved words in one language or another, and it is hard to understand the meaning of your logic.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it helped a lot here. Thanks also for the question formatting tips. Could you suggest the ideal way for me to edit the question?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the column names in your question.